# Add button inside a new div created dynamically with a button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building kind of a form.

Trying to insert a button into a new div created dynamically with javascript. Apparently, the code isn't working because the new div created is a local variable inside the function that created it.

Without the additional button, the code is working fine.
The idea is that the additional button add extra inputs of the original type of input of the Form.

Any advice of how could I accomplish this?

HTML:

```
<div id="dynamicInputs">
</div>
Título de la pregunta: <input name="qName" type="text"><br>
Tipo: <select name="inputSelect">
  <option value="text">Respuesta corta</option>
  <option value="radio">Selección múltiple</option>
  <option value="checkbox">Checkboxes</option>
  <option value="textarea">Desarrollo</option>
</select><br>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Agregar pregunta" onclick="addAllInputs('dynamicInputs', document.myForm.qName.value, document.myForm.inputSelect.value)">
```

Javascript:

```
    //agegar pregunta en formulario
var counterDynInput = 0;

function addAllInputs(divName, qName, inputType){
     var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
     var newDivName = "";

     newDivName = "divInputs_" + (counterDynInput + 1);
     newDiv.setAttribute("id", newDivName);
     newDiv.innerHTML = 
     (counterDynInput + 1) 
     + ". " 
     + inputLabel(qName) 
     + "<br>" 
     + inputFields(inputType)
     + "<hr>";

     addButtonToDiv(newDivName);
     counterDynInput++;
     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newDiv);
}

function inputLabel(qName){
     var putStr = "";
     putStr = "<input type='text' name='qLabel' value='" + qName + "' placeholder='Título de la pregunta...'>";
     return putStr;
}

function inputFields(inputType){
     var putStr = "";
     putStr = "<input type='" + inputType + "' name='myInputs[]'><br>";
     return putStr;
}

function addButtonToDiv(newDivName){
     var btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
     var div = document.getElementById(newDivName);
     div.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Comment: When you call `addButtonToDiv` the div is not yet appended to the DOM, meaning you dont find it to add the button. Choose between concatenating HTML to make new content, or working with the DOM - dont try to mix both.

Comment: @Jamiec ok I understand that, but then how can I get from outside of the function the `id` of the new divs created dynamically?

Comment: @Jamiec can you please elaborate a little bit more on how would you do it by concatenating HTML?